# SCSS/SASS function. VW minus pixels

Tags: sass

The problem is: I can't get where is the mistake here:

```
  @function calcSize($value) {
  $containerWidth: calc(100vw - 405px);
  $initialContainer: 1278;
  $result: $value * $containerWidth / $initialContainer;
  @return $result;
}
```

I'm trying to use it:

```
.module-title {
font-weight: 700;
font-size: calcSize(45);
}
```

But I get mistake: "Undefined operation "45 * calc(100vw - 405px)""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The calc() function needs to be sent to the client, so that the `100vw` element can be re-calculated every time the browser is resized.

However, you've used it in a server-side formula (`$value * $containerWidth / $initialContainer`) which needs to be processed *before* sending it to the browser.

What you probably need to do is have Sass render a `calc()` formula with all the parts in, which will then be sent to the client to calculate:

```
@function calcSize($value) {
  $initialContainer: 1278;
  $result: calc($value * (100vw - 405px) / $initialContainer);
  @return $result;
}
```

(Theoretically, SCSS could work out that that's what you meant, but it might be quite complex to implement.)